# Scrapy: output empty

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to extract data from [page](https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-aaron-morrow-md-greensboro-nc-us). But I get an empty output. What is the problem?

spider:

```
class Ratemds(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ratemds'
    allowed_domains = ['ratemds.com']

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.50747 OPRGX/60.0.3255.50747',
    }

    def start_requests(self): 
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-aaron-morrow-md-greensboro-nc-us' , callback=self.profile)

    def profile(self, response):
 
        item =  {
                'url': response.request.url,
                'Image': response.css('.doctor-profile-image::attr(src)').get(),
                'First_and_Last_Name': response.css('h1::text').get()
            }
        yield item
```

output:

```
{'url': 'https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-aaron-morrow-md-greensboro-nc-us', 'Image': None, 'First_and_Last_Name': None}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging, any idea where to begin?

Comment: In the end of your profile function, just add yield {"item":item}  after item dictionary.

Comment: @SamsulIslam No, I think I need to pass additional parameters when requesting

Comment: I get no `h1` in that URL. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy empty output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62610604/scrapy-empty-output)