# Scrapy empty output

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to extract data from [page](https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-aaron-morrow-md-greensboro-nc-us). But I get an empty output. What is the problem?

spider:

```
class Ratemds(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ratemds'
    allowed_domains = ['ratemds.com']

    custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.50747 OPRGX/60.0.3255.50747',
    }

    def start_requests(self): 
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-aaron-morrow-md-greensboro-nc-us' , callback=self.profile)

    def profile(self, response):
 
        item =  {
                'url': response.request.url,
                'Image': response.css('.doctor-profile-image::attr(src)').get(),
                'First_and_Last_Name': response.css('h1::text').get()
            }
        yield item
```

output:

```
{'url': 'https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-aaron-morrow-md-greensboro-nc-us', 'Image': None, 'First_and_Last_Name': None}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601706/scrapy-output-empty

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this website has captcha protection. And when you try to collect information from it you are redirecting to the page, like this one:
[image: error_page]

and as you can see this page not contains information which you are looking for.
To collect information from such website you can try the following:

1. Use scrapy-selenium/splash to collect information.
2. use captcha solving tools like death-by-captcha , anticaptcha or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to do with the use of [`css()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.css) method. Consider using [`xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.xpath) instead:

For example to extract a text,

```
response.xpath("//td[@class='name']/span/text()").extract()
```